# Scala: Setting programatically a break-point to be recognized by IntelliJ

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea

In Visual Studio / C# I can easily set programatically a break-point. Is there any similar feature available for IntelliJ/Scala-Plugin and the Scala language ?

To clarify: In C# you can call an API function

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

and then the Debugger in VS stops like with any breakpoint, set in the IDE.

Comment: Scala uses the same debugging tools as java does with Intellij. What do you mean by "programatically"?

Comment: I've edited my question to be more specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of such a feature, but in any programming environment you can get away with an adhoc solution: just define a method `debugBreak`, add a breakpoint to it and then use that. By example:

```
def debugBreak() {
  println("Breakpoint hit!") // Manually set a breakpoint here
}

//.... then somwhere in your code base
if (<<some condition>>) {
  debugBreak
}
```

That's it. Everytime the condition is met, the debugger will stop and you just need to go up the stack one frame.

As an aside, most of the time a better and simpler soluttion is to just set a conditional breakpoint in IntelliJ (essentially pasting your condition expression in the "condition" field). See https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-breakpoints.html.

However sometimes IntelliJ is unable to evaluate your expression, so in those cases the adhoc solution described above is a useful substitute.

Comment: Ok, I've used that solution, thought there might be a distinct API call like in VS available.

Comment: In VS with `Debugger.Break()` it's possible to attach to the process if no debugger is attached yet. This is the main advantage. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break(v=vs.110).aspx: "If no debugger is attached, users are asked if they want to attach a debugger. If users say yes, the debugger is started. If a debugger is attached, the debugger is signaled with a user breakpoint event, and the debugger suspends execution of the process just as if a debugger breakpoint had been hit."